# Errors after upgrading to Babel 7

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

This is being thrown upon running `npm start`

```
/Users/Gabe/esports-calendar/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:178
    throw new Error(`Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In ${filepath}`);
          ^

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /Users/Gabe/esports-calendar/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-ie/index.js
```

Comment: @Peter Thats where I'm confused, I don't know where host is being imported, or even what it is.

Comment: @Peter updated to add rest of event.js -- Here is the error shown when inspecting: https://puu.sh/DYR0P/e02013e65f.png

Comment: @Peter Done, but the issue persists. I am getting an Autoprefixed warning, however, could this be the source of the problem?: 

`Replace Autoprefixer browsers option to Browserslist config.
  Use browserslist key in package.json or .browserslistrc file.

  Using browsers option cause some error. Browserslist config 
  can be used for Babel, Autoprefixer, postcss-normalize and other tools.

  If you really need to use option, rename it to overrideBrowserslist.

  Learn more at:
  https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#readme
  https://twitter.com/browserslist`

Comment: @Peter Razzle is up to date at version 3.0.0

Comment: ok so when you 'upgraded to babel 7', what exactly did you do?

Comment: @Peter 'npm audit fix --force', then ran the npx babel-upgrade. There were still errors with breaking changes so I went through and fixed those up.

Comment: please add the complete package.json and any other config files that are relevant such as .babelrc and razzle.config.js.

Comment: @Peter Whats the best way to add these? I'm unable to paste the completed files due to code inbalance with description -- they are long files.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you reset this project to it's state BEFORE you ran `npm audit fix --force`. Assuming you are using git for version control, if that is true, you can run `git reset --hard` to set the current branch to the last commit.

The reason for this is that you tried to manually update your project to babel 7.  Razzle doesn't work this way; its goal is to simplify developer tooling by removing certain responsibilties from the developer.

1. go into your package.json file and change the version of razzle:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "razzle": "^3.0.0",
  etc...
}
```

2. delete your `node_modules` directory.
3. perform `npm i` to reinstall the packages.

Comment: Where should I add this, replace the import line in event.js? Or add it to config? (Sorry, new to this)

Comment: Changing this throws the following error:
`/Users/Gabe/esports-calendar/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6325
    const err = new SyntaxError(message);
                ^

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/Gabe/esports-calendar/src/common/stores/event.js: Unterminated string constant (5:24)`

Comment: Ok fixed the syntax, but the initial error still persists. Any ideas?

Comment: Its not, I'm upgrading npm packages for the company I'm interning for.

Comment: can you please add to your original post which packages you upgraded?  I am running very low on time and the more detail you can provide, the better our chances will be for solving this problem

Comment: what exactly do you mean by reset it to it's state? The first thing I did was npm upgrade, then npm audit fix, then npm audit fix --force. Should I do that in a different order? Thanks

Comment: Ok, I went through these steps but am now getting errors having to do with the breaking changes of the babel upgrade. How do you suggest I go about fixing these?

Comment: @ScottMyers I have no idea what errors are being thrown.  Additionally, this question is getting off topic.  Please try to update your original question to reflect the current problem.  Comments aren't intended for this amount of back and forth.

Comment: Updated to reflect current issue